# running a command with ruby mine

Tags: rubymine

I would like to execute the following command in rubymine ide
`export RACK_ENV=development APP_ROLES=batch; jruby -J-Xmx2056m  -S trinidad -e development`

I am not able to get the ruby run configuration without a ruby script.
[image]

I tried running it as gem command

`/Users/gaurav/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/bin/jruby --1.8 -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/gaurav/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/bin/jruby -J-Xmx2056m -S trinidad -e development`

But doesn't seem to work that way cause it tries to run jruby using jruby

Comment: You can try using the `Rails Server` run/debug configuration instead and select `Trinidad` from the server combobox.

Comment: it executes `/Users/gaurav/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/bin/jruby --1.8 -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/gaurav/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8@goshposh/bin/trinidad --threadsafe -p 9292 -e development -J-Xmx2056m -S trinidad -e development` which doesn't work

Comment: thanks created one http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-13725